# How to rewrite src tags with htaccess dynamically

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a project setup with completely separate child projects in subdirectories.
I want the links set to images and other file types set inside my project* folders to get them relative to project* itself. However there are some exceptions. I figured the best way to do it is to check if file exist relative to root/ first and if not, then try to get it relative to project* folder.

This is my solution so far, which works fine for only project1. **How can i make it dynamically working for all projects?**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/root/subfolder/project1/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(gif|jpg|png|svg|js|css))$ root/subfolder/project1/$1 [L]
```

My folder structure is like this example:

```
root:
     - index
     - .htaccess
     - asstes/img/
     - subfolder/
          - project1/
                - index
                - script.js
                - style.css
                - img/
        - project2/
                - index
                - script.js
                - style.css
                - img/
```

Comment: Any attempt to find a dynamic solution for this would mean some processing logic. But for that an easier alternative would be to use a classical routing script in the main folder which can decide by itself which file to read from the file system and to hand it out as a response to a request. That allows you to use any language you like for the implementation. The typical solution uses a php based routing script.

Comment: unfortunately this is not possible based on our current setup. Like i already said, the example above is working fine, but obviously we would need to replicate those lines for each project. Any idea, how we can convert it into a dynamic version?

Comment: No, I am not aware of such feature. But even if you are able to find some exotic module for your http server which allows for such thing - it would be exactly that: exotic. Which is a typical indication of an XY problem: someone trying to solve an issue in a way he thinks the issue can be solved instead of solving the issue the way it should be solved. ;-)